# Pweave cannot import local module

Tags: python, pweave

I'm trying to import code from a local module into a pweave document, and I can't get it to work.

I have the following files

```
- foo.pmd 
- bar.py
- __init__.py
```

Contents of foo.pmd:

````
```python
import bar
bar.foobar()
```
````

Contents of bar.py:

```
def foobar():
    return(1)
```

Then I run `pweave foo.md` and the output fails:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------ImportError
Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-1-1c3509f6dae7> in <module>()
----> 1 import bar
      2 bar.foobar()
ImportError: No module named
'bar'
```

I think this should work?  Or am I trying to do something that's not possible?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. My solution:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
import myfantasticmodule
```

I think the problem is, that the current working directory is not in the Python-Path  where Python looks for modules (I have no idea why this problem only occurs with pweave).

```
os.getcwd()
```

gives you the "current working directory" and

```
sys.path.append()
```

adds this directory to the Python-path (only for this session! So you don't have to delete it at the end).

Comment: Please add a description it would be helpful than just a piece of code.

Comment: Just wanted to add this is still helpful and relevant. Thank you!